# TinyMCE image add from custom gallery with Ruby on Rails

Tags: image, tinymce, wysiwyg

I use TinyMCE textarea editor in my Ruby on Rails project. I have db table with uploaded pictures. I have section with articles, so I need add some images to articles.

My bad fast solution:
I have "gallery" until textarea with TinyMCE and when I click on image from gallery JS copy image link and add this link to the end of textarea. But this solution is not very good.

Do you have any good suggestion/solution for "add images to articles"? Wordpress have a nice "engine" for this my problem.
(sorry for my english)

I don't have to use TineMce, I can use whatever WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for an image upload tool for tinymce: http://pascal.vanhecke.info/2005/08/25/image-upload-plugin-for-tinymce/

Comment: It's look nice, but it's only for TinyMCE 2.5, it's too old, but I try it